# Parallax - end of page out of view because of absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I have a parallax website built using [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) and it works great until I get to the end of the page. I want a `<div class="footer"></div>` to be the last / furthest point you can scroll on the page.

Currently, i'm left with either a massive white gap if i view it on a large screen or im unable to scroll down any further to view the footer on a small screen.

I'm using the `data-0="top:4580px;" data-11000="top:1580px;" data-end="top:=830px;"` attributes to set the parallax effect.

I want it to behave like a normal non-parallax effect at the bottom of the page but if i dont set `data` attributes then because the rest of the page has a parallax effect this footer appears at 0px on the page.

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing your code. The gap may appear as a result of the `forceHeight` option which defaults to `true`.

Comment: `forceheight` is set to true along with smooth scrolling. However if I change it to false, I can't scroll down past my viewport.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way that I say:

set a width:100% and height:100% div to a z-index:-1 div and set it to left:0; and top:0;
and set a nice background for it.

```
.endofPage{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   z-index:-1;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
```

if end of your page is out of view (I mean if you have free stage and view) **this way is really working well**